# Edit permissions, but not to all documents

Tags: document-library, permissions, document, sharepoint-library

I have a document library having documents (eg: word,pdf etc).
User has add and edit permission to the library (required)
But user should be able to edit a particular document.
Can I set the permission as read only for documents for users with edit permission on a library?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can set Item level permissions on Document Library. Click the context menu/List Item Menu and click Permissions. Here you can Stop Inheriting Permissions from Library and set unique permissions for the Document.

[image: List Item - Manage Permissions]

And once you stop the inheritance of the Document, it will say Item has unique permissions, see below:

[image]